# Windows command line string replace removes "!"

Tags: windows, command-line

I have this little snippet that replaces `production:false` with `production:true`.

```
(FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type test.js|find /n /v """') do (

    set "line=%%B"

    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:production:false=production:true%%"
        FOR /F "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.

)) >test-temp.js

move /Y test-temp.js test.js
```

So far so good, but, in the test.js it says something like:

```
if ( !production ) {}
```

The thing is, **the "!" is removed by the above command** as well. Any idea how does happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `delayedexpansion` invoked.

Running your snippet (which is all you give us) against your single line of provided data simply reproduced the data line verbatim.

with `delayedexpansion`, the `!` disappeared as you describe.

---

To fix (with `delayedexpansion` in effect

```
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type q19406461.txt|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"

    if defined line (
             call set "line=echo.%%line:production:false=production:true%%"
             FOR /F "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.

)) >test-temp.js
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: I indeed have `delayedexpansion` invoked. How would I overcome the `!` replace?

Answer (score 2):

This is a robust method and uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Put `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file.

```
@echo off
type "test.js"|repl "production:false" "production:true" >"test-temp.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

Peter already diagnosed the problem with delayed expansion. Here is a bit more explanation.

FOR variables are expanded before delayed expansion. So the line `set "line=%%B"` first sets the value to `if ( !production ) {}`, but then delayed expansion sees the unpaired `!` and strips it. If it were paired, it would attempt to expand the variable in between.

Here is a summary of the order of variable expansion (practical, but a bit imprecise):

1) Normal expansion:  argument (%1) and variable (%var%). Arguments take precedence over variables.

2) FOR variable: %%A

3) Delayed expansion: !var!

4) SET /A variables

See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053) for a more exact description of how lines are parsed and expanded.

It is possible to use delayed expansion within your loop without corrupting `!` literals if you toggle delayed expansion on and off. This is preferred over using the CALL syntax because it is faster, does not muck with `%` literals, does not double quoted carets, protects against all poison characters, even when they are not quoted.

The use of delayed expansion makes the code much simpler, faster, and more reliable:

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
(FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type test.js|find /n /v """') do (
  set "line=%%B"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if defined line (
    echo(!line:production:false=production:true!
  ) ELSE echo(
  endlocal
)) >test-temp.js
move /Y test-temp.js test.js
endlocal
```

Note that I use `ECHO(` instead of `ECHO.` because the latter can fail in some obscure scenarios. `ECHO(` looks like it would cause problems with block parentheses, but it actually always works without any problems.

Note that I would still not use the above code. Instead I would use the REPL.BAT utility as foxidrive has in his answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. I don't know who to give the credit for answering the question though as all of you helped. :(